# Use a real Windows hard-drive to boot off Qemu?

Tags: qemu

I'm looking for a Windows equivalent of Unixish:

`qemu -hda /dev/sda`

How does the Windows version of it look like, assuming the device I'd like to boot is under the drive letter E:? `qemu -hda E:` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In our `win_srv.xml` config file:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source file='/dev/[hostname]/win_srv_vm_data'/>
  <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
</disk>
```

On the command line it ends up looking like:

```
/usr/bin/kvm ... -drive file=/dev/[hostname]/win_srv_vm_data,if=ide,index=2,format=raw,cache=none
```

The Windows VM picks this up as its `E` drive, but you could easily reconfigure the mapping in Windows to make it `D` or whatever you wanted.

I should also note we're using mapper and fakeRAID, so the way our drive is carved up and devices are laid out is pretty weird.  the `/dev/[hostname]/win_srv_vm_data` should go to a raw partition, but it sounds like you already were anticipating that.

Comment: You're reffering to /usr/bin/kvm, but I'm talking about running Qemu under Windows. How does that relate?

Comment: Ah, well your question wasn't very clear.  It reads that you're looking to mount a raw disk from a Unix Host in a Windows VM.  Or it reads any number of a dozen other ways, looking at it again.  Perhaps you should clarify and you might get answers that better suit your needs.